# show dynamic view in email with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email, view

I get templates that users upload in project and project stores them on public/templates.

Each template has a folder and the folder has two files. First preview.png, second template.blade.php

When I show the template preview, it shows as it must be shown but when I try to send email with this template, I get this error `View [default1.template] not found`.

This is config/view.php :

```
'paths' => [
    template_path(),
    resource_path('views'),
],
```

This is my helper ( the template_path() function):

```
if(!function_exists('template_path')){
    function template_path(){
        return public_path('templates');
    }
}
```

In AppServiceProvider I use this code:

```
$this->loadViewsFrom(template_path(), 'template');
```

This is my mailable file (SendMail.php) :

```
$view = $this->notification->template->path . '.template';

if (!is_null($this->notification->replyToEmail))
    return $this->view('template::'.$view)->subject($this->notification->subject)->replyTo($this->notification->replyToEmail, $this->notification->replyToName);
else
    return $this->view('template::'.$view)->subject($this->notification->subject);
```

Finally this is my send email code:

```
Mail::to($this->subscriber->email)->send(
    new SendMail(
        $this->subscriber,
        $this->notification,
        $this->products,
        $this->group,
    )
);
```

**EDIT:**
When I get `dd(View::exists('template::'.$view))` in AppServiceProvider, this view exists but when I get `dd(View::exists('template::'.$view))` in Mailable file (SendMail.php) it throws nothing.

**Edit 2:**
This templates exists in `/public/templates` directory.

the `.template` is a blade file that it name is `template.blade.php`

---

**Note:** It's ok when i run in local. but it throws error in server

In server, i put this code in index.php file

```
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return __DIR__;
});
```

And put all **my files and directories except public directory** to host **root**. and put **public directory contents** to `/public_html`

Comment: Are your templates located in the `public_path()`? So in your `/public` directory of your project? Additionally, you are using `.template` files. Returning a view in Laravel **must** be a `blade` file for as far as I know.

Comment: @EricLandheer Thanks eric. yes my templates exists on /public directory.
and the .template file is a blade file that name is template.blade.php

Comment: @EricLandheer  it's ok when i run in local. but it throws error in server. i edited question

Comment: Have you tried clearing the view with `php artisan view:clear` and the config with `php artisan config:clear`? Are the files readable on the server, do you have the right access (I guess so, since they are in public path). **Edit**: Do you see the right directory being logged if you use `public_path()` on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I store my views in storage and connect storage views to controllers. this was a solution and this error `View [default1.template] not found` was solved